# Destructuring a string with multiple delimiters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have filenames of the form:

```
const fn = 'xy_20181023_ABCD.jpg';
```

I would like to separate this into the variables `x, y, date, data` such that:

```
console.log({x, y, date, data});
// {
//     data: "ABCD.jpg"
//     date: "20181023"
//     x: "x"
//     y: "y"
// }
```

I know I can do it like this:

```
const [temp, date, data] = fn.split('_');
const [x, y] = temp[0]
```

but my question is: is it possible to somehow do the assignment in a single line? Bonus points if it's still easily readable.

Cheers,

P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following

```js
const fn = 'xy_20181023_ABCD.jpg';
const [[x,y], date, data] = fn.split('_');
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(date);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @Batters - Glad to help you mate!